# Option to delete value in metabox

Tags: metabox

I'm making a metabox with a textbox that displays the value of the metakey if I user types and saves data. What I need help with is how the user can delete previous entries as well as edit them if they need to. I've looked all over and can't find anything.

This is what I have to display entries:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'brk_news_update', true) ) : ?>

<?php
$mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('brk_news_update');
foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
echo "$value <br />"; }?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [delete_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta) to delete a value.

Example:

```
delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'brk_news_update');
```

If you want to update it, then use [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'brk_news_update','value');
```

Comment: What's the best way to make it as a button?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of button you need. so check [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for example

Comment: In the metabox, I'm looking for a way to have a link with edit or delete options next to the value. Example: Value from metakey | (edit) | (delete)